# When does the error function in ajax request gets called

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ajax has an error function in an ajax request. When does this error function gets called. Can I know if the error function gets called if its due to an connection error.How do i get the particular error from this function. How does connection errors show in ajax? When I'm using localhost can I test connection errors using ajax error function. Thank you

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'fetch.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: holder,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (returnArr) {
                
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error occured');
               //this error function
            },
            timeout: 10000,
        });
    }
```

Comment: read the docs here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: When the request errors

Comment: Network errors, unsuccessful response status and for `datatype: 'json'`, JSON parsing errors all trigger the error handler. The arguments to the error handler are `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. You can use the last two for details on what went wrong